# Creating HTML5 canvas patterns and filling stuff with them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm having difficulties with `.createPattern(image,"repeat")`.

1. Can I fill a square with my own pattern created by `.toDataURL()` and `.createPattern()`?
2. Can I fill a square with a pattern, which is the current canvas?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.strokeRect(0.5, 0.5, 10, 10);
context.arc(5.5, 5.5, 3, 0, Math.PI);
context.rect(3, 3, 1, 1);
context.rect(7, 3, 1, 1);
context.stroke();

var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
context.drawImage(img, 10, 10); // works

context.beginPath();
var pattern = context.createPattern(img, "repeat"); // doesn't work
context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
var pattern2 = context.createPattern(canvas, "repeat"); // doesn't work
context.fillStyle = pattern2;
context.fillRect(120, 20, 100, 100);
context.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240" style="border: solid darkblue 1px;background-color: aliceblue"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to create a separate canvas for the pattern as you cannot self-reference the canvas for use with patterns.

The reason is that when you reference the original canvas you are trying to draw to, the pattern will have the same size and will only draw one instance as there is no room for more than that.

So to make it work you need to define a pattern of a smaller size, hence we need a separate canvas or image and pass that in as a source for the pattern.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// create the off-screen canvas
var canvasPattern = document.createElement("canvas");
canvasPattern.width = 10;
canvasPattern.height = 10;
var contextPattern = canvasPattern.getContext("2d");

// draw pattern to off-screen context
contextPattern.beginPath();
contextPattern.strokeRect(0.5, 0.5, 10, 10);
contextPattern.arc(5.5, 5.5, 3, 0, Math.PI);
contextPattern.rect(3, 3, 1, 1);
contextPattern.rect(7, 3, 1, 1);
contextPattern.stroke();

// now pattern will work with canvas element    
var pattern = context.createPattern(canvasPattern,"repeat");
context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
context.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240" style="border: solid darkblue 1px;background-color: aliceblue"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hmmm so that's how it works. Strange it doesn't accept self-repeating. Thanks.

Comment: oh and why isn't it accepting the image as pattern `var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();`?

Comment: @VixinG the problem is that the whole canvas is used as the pattern so it will only draw one instance since it would be the same size (if you removed your beginPath you will see that in the original code). The off-screen canvas or image has a different size which is necessary for making the pattern. Hope that made sense :)

Comment: @VixinG for the same reason, the image reference the canvas and has the same size (no room for pattern)