# Canvas fill - Diagonal Hatch

Tags: html5-canvas

Good morning,

I'm working on a project where I need to draw generic polygons and fill them on the HTML5 Canvas. I need to fill the shapes with diagonal lines, in a configurable color. I currently see two solutions to this problem.

The first is to figure out the math and algorithm to draw colored lines over the shape itself, using moveTo and lineTo functions. While this is possible, I have no ideas how to start with the algorithm.

The second would be to use the Fill Pattern feature in the HTML5 Canvas, by creating a small PNG (say 5x5), and draw the pattern in that. I've successfully implemented this, but do not think it's possible to change the color of this image on the fly.

Has anyone worked on something similar to this? I know there are other libraries or options to use rather than the HTML5 Canvas, but we are trying to only use basic HTML/CSS/JavaScript before evaluating outside libraries.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the pattern (using canvas) into a separate canvas element and use the DataURL methods to *fill* that texture into your main drawing canvas.

Pretty sure [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518107/creating-html5-canvas-patterns-and-filling-stuff-with-them) details the sort of thing you're after.

Comment: That looks about right. Thanks very much! I'll work that up and see if it is right.

Comment: Let me know your experiences, I keep wanting to start a project where I'll need to something very similar!

Comment: That's it except you don't need the `toDataURL()`. `Context2d.createPattern()` does accept `<canvas>` element directly.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked out well! I'll have to have a play myself with the `createPattern` method